# Typescript isn't inferring that an object is defined even after check

Tags: typescript

I have code in the following format:

```
interface Data {
   isAvailable: boolean;
}

const foo = (data: Data | undefined, error: boolean) => {
   const hasError = error || !data;
   if (!hasError) {
      if (data.isAvailable) // do something here. this is the line where I'm getting an error
   }
   return hasError;
}
```

Typescript is giving me a `Object is possibly undefined` error on the `data` in the `if (data.isAvalable)` check even though I've checked `hasError`. I can fix it by adding `&& data` to the `if (hasError)`, but that duplicates code and shouldn't Typescript be able to infer that data is defined without the explicit check?

Comment: Isn't that logic backwards anyway? `hasError` implies `data` is _not_ defined.

Comment: Is this a typo?  Of course `if (error || !data) {data.isAvailable}` would be a problem; you're testing the opposite of what you want, I think.  If you change it from `if (hasError)` to `if (!hasError)`, does that convey what you're trying to do?  If so you will get the desired behavior when [TS4.4 comes out](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#cfa-aliased-conditions). If not then I am very confused about what you are trying to do here.  Please advise.

Comment: Whoops I did have a typo. I've updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 4.4 will provide support for [control flow analysis of aliased conditions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#cfa-aliased-conditions), at which point your test will just work as-is:

```
const foo = (data: Data | undefined, error: boolean) => {
    const hasError = error || !data;
    if (!hasError) {
        if (data.isAvailable) { } // okay
    }
    return hasError;
}
```

[Playground link for TS4.4 beta](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg5YAZwEEA3OYAGzgCNqIAuZOgezcbhAG5cBfXLgRsQxMMhgdkAXmQAKACYY4LdJmQAfZAFcQiiDFARFAGmTQobKC3acI3AJSyAfDnyERYiQAs4xAFEoKyhZC2DrLW0AQmVMPkIiGAVov0CIqGc8RMTgZKUVADoSCipaBggs5H5kAHpa5DYAazgATw8CQUSoCDAdKBBkNKCQvn4gA)

For versions of TypeScript before 4.4, you will need to refactor your code so that the compiler understands what you're doing.  For example, do the test inline instead of aliasing it:

```
const foo = (data: Data | undefined, error: boolean) => {
    if (!(error || !data)) {
        if (data.isAvailable) { } // okay
    }
    return error || !data;
}
```

It requires some duplication, unfortunately.

[Playground link for TS4.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg5YAZwEEA3OYAGzgCNqIAuZOgezcbhAG5cBfXLgRsQxMMhgdkAXmQAKACYY4LdJmQAfZAFcQiiDFARFAGmTQobKC3acI3AJSyAfDnyFgMBQEJ5l6y1tH2VMR2c8QiiibyUVADoSCipaBggI5H5kAHps5DYAazgATw8CQSioCDAdKBALKCsoIOQQlT5BXCA)

Comment: it looks like you are still getting the `Object is possibly undefined` error in the playground for TS4.3?

Comment: D'oh, okay let me fix that.  This is what happens when I'm not careful.  There might not be a non-repetitive way to do this in TS4.3 and below.

Answer (score -1):

The function signature `data: Data | undefined` means that `data` can be of type  `Data` or underfined.

for the moment the `data` is undefined, TS does not know about `isAvailable` field.

What you can do, is something like:

```
if (data?.isAvailable) {
```

Ref. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg4AZwEEA3OYAGzgCMqIAuZWge1YbhAG5cBfXLgSsQRMMhjtkAXmQAKACYY4zdJmQAfZAFcQCiDFAQFAGmTQorKMzYcIXAJQyAfDnwFho8QAs4RAKJQllAy5kFWmloAhEqYvATIwDDyUb4B4VBOeAkJSfKxcAD8AHTE5JQ09BBZ7jkEAPT1yAqsyESsALYQYN6gAObI3tAQxcg9xIlEY0PIVEbIAO5DUCgAkgDkHch93WD9yFxhwbUJAqe1K2DaUCCDfoHBvAJAA

Comment: I think the goal is to get TypeScript to narrow the type, which it absolutely can do (even in the current version, just not quite the way the OP did it).